# How to remove the port number from URL in a nginx site

Tags: linux, unix, nginx, webserver, nginx-config

In an URL, I see something like: `http://example.com:8000/page`. Even though I manage to access the site by typing URL without the port, it is added there when I go to any sub-page.

I used to have a Python-based web server instead of nginx, it worked awfully, however, the port number was never there. This is why I still hope there is a way to hide a non-standard port (without changing it to standard) because the Python web server didn't show one.

I redirect port 80 >> 8000, by the way.

Is there a feature in the nginx config to hide non-standard port from a site? If no, maybe some other method?

My config:

```
server {

  listen 8000;

  access_log /logs/access.log;
  error_log /logs/error.log;

  index index.html;
  server_name example.com;

  error_page 404 errors/404.html; 

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

}
```

Comment: Show us an example of what does your nginx configuration looks like anonymizing the  personal/site data so we can know what is happening.

Comment: If your server is listening on port 8000 then you can't hide that from the URL. If you don't want the port number to appear, then you need to configure the server so it listens on a standard port (80 or 443).

Comment: @flaixman I've added it.

Comment: don't you have a port 80 or 443 configuration?

Comment: No. I have to use 8000 port. My main question is though, why does Python built-in web server not show the port in a URL but nginx does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured out that

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

solves it.